# Reading Chart information for VSTO Excel Add-in

Tags: c#, excel

I am attempting to write a VSTO Add-in for Excel 2007 in C# and I am having problems reading values from previously generated charts.  The Add-in duplicates a portion of a large data set and then replots the data with the same properties but different worksheet and sourcedata.  When I attempt to obtain the chart title (and other properties) from the original worksheet, it causes an exception.  I have attempted to use several variations of Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Charts as a starting point but I have been unsuccessful.  My assumption is that I am not referring to the old chart properly.

any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After some digging, I realized I should have been reading properties from the SeriesCollection of the chart. Something similar to the following worked

snippet
     Excel.ChartObjects xlCharts = (Excel.ChartObjects)newWorkSheet.ChartObjects(Type.Missing);

```
 Excel.ChartObject myChart = (Excel.ChartObject)xlCharts.Add(10, 60, 720, 432);
 Excel.Chart chart = myChart.Chart;
 Excel.ChartObject oldchartObject = (Excel.ChartObject)VstoWorksheet.ChartObjects(1);
 Excel.Chart oldchart = oldchartObject.Chart;
 Excel.SeriesCollection seriesCollection = (Excel.SeriesCollection)chart.SeriesCollection(Type.Missing);
 Excel.SeriesCollection oldSeriesCollection = (Excel.SeriesCollection)oldchart.SeriesCollection(Type.Missing);
 Excel.Series oSeries;
 for (int i = 1; i <= (ColumnCount - 2); i++)
 {
     oSeries = seriesCollection.NewSeries();
     Excel.Series oOldSeries = oldSeriesCollection.Item(i);
     oOldSeries = (Excel.Series)oldchart.SeriesCollection(i);
     oSeries.MarkerStyle = oOldSeries.MarkerStyle;
     oSeries.Name = oOldSeries.Name;
 }
```